# sort a unique list of string in reverse chronological order

Tags: java, sorting

I want to sort a unique list of string in reverse chronological order. **Which collection** to use and the **best way** to implement it.

My Soln :
take the strings in the list, and make a comparator 
   pass the list,and an object of this comparator implemented class to the Collections sort operation

```
public class SortStringsReverse {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List l = new ArrayList();
        l.add("ABC");
        l.add("ZXY");

        StringComparator comparatorObj = new StringComparator();
        Collections.sort(l, comparatorObj);
        for(Object s: l){
            System.out.println("values are " + (String)s);
        }
    }
}

class StringComparator implements Comparator{

    public int compare(Object arg0, Object arg1) {
        return ((String)arg1).compareTo((String)arg0);//return ((String)arg0).compareTo((String)arg1);
    }

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "reverse chronological order"? Unless you've got some time format within the string, it's hard to understand how you'll do the comparison. Did you mean "reverse lexical order"?

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "best way"?  Most efficient performance/memory or easiest to code?

Comment: You mix java 1.4 with 1.5. Use `List<String>`,`StringComparator implements Comparator<String>` , `public int compare(String arg0, String arg1)`. Compiler will cast for you

Comment: @John sorry for misleading words  you got it right

Comment: @jowierun i mean most efficient with respect to performance

Comment: @ajozwik will this code not run correctly on java 1.4 ? please reply

Comment: for(Object s: l) is from java 1.5

Answer (score 2):

Since you specified that you want **unique** items in a **sorted** manner, in Java the best tool for this is the [`TreeSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) (although any `SortedSet` implementation will do). Normally, the `TreeSet` class stores items in ascending order, but luckily we can change that with a custom `Comparator` object as an argument.

I'm assuming by your question that you want strings sorted in reverse *alphabetical* order since chronological order makes no sense here, but really you can implement your own `Comparator` as necessary. Now, the `Comparator` you provide will sort strings according to the original Java manner: strings farther down in the alphabet will be compared as coming after strings "closer" to the beginning of the alphabet (e.g. `"bananas".compareTo("zebra")` will return a positive result, `"zebra".compareTo("bananas")` a negative one. To reverse the alphabetical order, we can use this duality and reverse the order of comparisons; compare the second argument against the first, as such:

```
class StringComparator implements Comparator<String>{

    public int compare(String arg0, String arg1) {
        return arg1.compareTo(arg0);
    }

}
```

Now pass an object of that class into your `TreeSet<String>` object, and you should be set.

Comment: thanks for the reply and assuming correctly(as i used some wrong words).. the code you mentioned is same as mine(except the generics and treeSet), rite ?

Comment: The code is basically the same, but your question doesn't require a complicated solution. You should use a `TreeSet` rather than a `List`, because a `TreeSet` will guarantee two things: first, that all the items in it will be unique; second, that all the items will be sorted. This is a much better option than the `List`, where neither of these conditions are assured. I used generics in my example `Comparator` because it makes the code cleaner, and it removes the need for casting. Any other questions?